# Fill & Stoke width issue in html 5 canvas

Tags: html5-canvas

I want to draw a closed shape(Using paths) & my stroke width is 10.
Now,i want to fill that shape,i can fill it using fill() function of context.
But,when i want to change alpha of my shape,then stroke & fill area overlap at border of shape.

I want only fill the area of shape that remains black after my stroke.
I have attached image of explaining my problem.

[Click here to show shape with stork & fill bug.](http://jsfiddle.net/VzyKn/)

As you can see in jsfiddle,
           -- Color of overlapping area are composite color. That i don't want.
              I want it to be exactly same as in border(or stroke color with alpha).
           -- i am not enable to specify fill area of closed path.(there is no method of contexx.)
           -- I can't use "glabalCompositeOperation",because i am drawing more than 1 shapes in 1 canvas in my application.

Answer (score 1):

The effect you are getting seems to be a property of how canvas draws lines round a shape. Half the thickness of the line is drawn inside the shape and half outside the shape. One way round it is to draw the filled shape and the border as seperate paths. The changes to do this for your example are shown below. This will be more difficult with irregular shapes.

```
            var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
            var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
            var topLeftCornerX = 188;
            var topLeftCornerY = 50;
            var width = 200;
            var height = 100;
            var linewidth = 10;

            context.globalAlpha = 0.5;
            context.beginPath();
            context.moveTo(topLeftCornerX, topLeftCornerY);
            context.lineTo(topLeftCornerX+width,topLeftCornerY);
            context.lineTo(topLeftCornerX+width,topLeftCornerY+height);
            context.lineTo(topLeftCornerX,topLeftCornerY+height);
            context.closePath();
            context.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
            context.fill();
            context.beginPath();
            context.moveTo(topLeftCornerX-linewidth/2, topLeftCornerY-linewidth/2);
            context.lineTo(topLeftCornerX+width+linewidth/2,topLeftCornerY-linewidth/2);
            context.lineTo(topLeftCornerX+width+linewidth/2,topLeftCornerY+height+linewidth/2);
            context.lineTo(topLeftCornerX-linewidth/2,topLeftCornerY+height+linewidth/2);
            context.closePath();
            context.lineWidth = linewidth;
            context.strokeStyle = "#00FF00";
            context.stroke();
```

Comment: thanks for reply. But in my case,i always need to draw complex path. 1 solution i found is that to fill element first & then stroke it with using "globalCompositeOperation=copy". But i will only help when one want only 1 shape in canvas. But in my case i have already drawn many shapes on canvas,i need to draw another shape on top on other shapes. I can also draw that but i need to use temporary canvas and draw new shape on it,then using "drawImage" ,draw shape on main canvas. But i don't want temp canvas.